# Instabug Cordova Plugin crashing on network change

Tags: android, cordova, instabug

I am using the Cordova Instabug plugin:
https://github.com/elizabethrego/cordova-plugin-instabug

Everything is working well, except for when the network state of the device changes. The app basically just crashes.

I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.instabug.library.network.InstabugNetworkReceiver"
```

I can't find much to go on so really not sure where to start...

Comment: Can you try this one instead: https://github.com/Instabug/instabug-cordova

This is the one that we maintain ourselves.

Comment: Thanks I will check it out this morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that all of the issues I experienced with that plugin have been resolved with the official plugin:

https://github.com/Instabug/instabug-cordova

The API is exactly the same as well which is helpful but also perhaps the reason I missed it whilst looking for alternatives.